# php inside javascript how to destroy the $_GET variable?

Tags: php, javascript, variables, get

i want to make login/register site with Ajax, both of them have completed, but when it receive `$_GET` variable, there is some problem
Inside body, there is function `log()` and this is the main code problem

```
<?php
if($say!=null && $reg=="log")
{
?>
fontid.innerHTML = "<?php echo $say; ?>"
<?php
}
$say="";
?>
```

the `$say` variable will still remain even there is another code that change the fontid.innerHTML
FOR EXAMPLE

```
index.php?say=You%20must%20login%20first&reg=log
```

then in my page will display You must login first, okay, then i press login with no input, there will be error like "please dont leave empty field", after that if i press another things that might change the `fontid.innerHTML` into null, the $say value will still remain...the main point is how to destory the $say ?? Sorry if it is too long

Comment: How do you perform the AJAX reuqest?

Comment: i have absolutely no idea what you are trying to ask. but to destroy a variable, you can use the unset() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function

Comment: how to comment it here ?It say too long

Comment: i have use unset and  the $say still display with its value

Comment: read the docs on how to unset variable within the global scope, its right there

Comment: OR the $say cannot be change inside javascript ?

Comment: maybe learn first what php does, its executed server side (before any javascript and completely independent of it). javascript is client side.

Comment: so...is it possible to unset php variable from javascript ?

Comment: no, you cant access php from javascript in any direct way (only through ajax/POST/GET you can send variables to it) my suggestion: search this site and the internet before asking questions here, everything you have asked so far is explained in detail on various sites that you will find with a simple search. and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're mixing up Javascript with PHP, be aware that this is not clean coding and you will at some point regret it, because your code will get unreadable. 
Where does your Code does appear, what you mean with `$_GET` variable problem because of a `log()` function?

'after that if i press another things that might change the fontid.innerHTML into null, the $say value will still remain'
it does not get null i think it gets an empty string like '', so you better do ask for that too: `if($say!=null && $say!='' && $reg=="log")`

A bit offtopic but might help you overall, a approach to clean up could be: 
create a file `ajax.php` and do all ajax mechanics in there (maybe use some kind of `$_POST['action']` which u can use use in a switch case to perform certain actions.

All returns should be json_encoded so your data you have to handle looks always same on return.
I use this function for that:

```
function jsondie($status, $array, $jsoutput){ 
    if(!is_array($array)) { jsondie('error', 'Not an array!', $array); }
    $return_values = array('status' => $status, 
                    'data' => $array,
                    'jsoutput' => $jsoutput);
    return json_encode($return_values);
}
```

Create your javascript with (eg) jquery $.ajax and use `dataType: 'json'` 
On the returned data you can easily check your stuff then.

```
jQuery.ajax("ajax.php", dataType: 'json', { action: 'login', username: username, password: password, captcha: captcha },
    function(ajaxdata) {
        if(typeof(ajaxdata.status)=='undefined') { 
            alert('error in your ajax function'); 
            // push that stuff to f12 console for firebug + chrome
            try { console.log(ajaxdata); } catch(e){}
            return false;
        } else if (ajaxdata.status == 'error'){
           // write it to some error dialog or field here 
           fontid.innerHTML = '<span class="error">'+ajaxdata.data+'</span>';
           // flush the returned data to the console
           try { console.log(ajaxdata.jsoutput); } catch(e){}
        } else {
           // all fine, write or do something on success
           //window.location = 'loggedin.php';
           fontid.innerHTML = ajaxdata.data; // this is the data coming from ajax.php
        }
    }
```

Maybe this helps you or someone other to get a cleaner approach for your planned project :-)

Max

Comment: thanks..but i think it is too much just for destory $_GET variable ?

Comment: Of course, this is a quite complete approach on creating ajax driven stuff without mixing php and js and keeping quite clean, which might be one of your basic issues here. for destroying the variable, follow Marks unset(). you may see mine as a ajax programming tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As @x4rf41 (and others...) said, [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)!

Here's your exact answer, copypasted from the doc...

```
   To unset() a global variable inside of a function, then use the $GLOBALS array to do so:
```

```
 function foo() 
 {
     unset($GLOBALS['bar']);
 }
```

Comment: tried it but the $say still no destroy

Comment: @JohanSurya it is not possible. You either re-define it (ie give it value) somewhere else after you unset it or use the same variable name in (e.g.) a function scope. Grab your php files, find all "$say" init and add an echo before the line where you change it. You'll find where you set it after it should have been destroyed